# Are static fields used to modify super class behaviour thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, subclass

If a subclass wants to modify the behaviour of inherited methods through static fields, is it thread safe?

More specifically:

```
class A (object):
  _m = 0
  def do(self):
     print self._m

class B (A):
  _m=1
  def test(self):
    self.do()

class C (A):
  _m=2
  def test(self):
    self.do()
```

Is there a risk that an instance of class B calling do() would behave as class C is supposed to, or vice-versa, in a multithreading environment? I would say yes, but I was wondering if somebody went through actually testing this pattern already.

Note: This is not a question about the pattern itself, which I think should be avoided, but about its consequences, as I found it in reviewing real life code.

Comment: This is probably a poor example of the actual issue - each class has a *different* `_m` variable.

Comment: That's the point: that's why they could be mixed up by different concurent threads

Answer (score 0):

First, remember that classes are objects, and static fields (and for that matter, methods) are attributes of said class objects.

So what happens is that `self.do()` looks up the `do` method in `self` and calls `do(self)`. `self` is set to whatever object is being called, which itself references one of the classes `A`, `B`, or `C` as its class. So the lookup will find the value of `_m` in the correct class.

Of course, that requires a correction to your code:

```
class A (object):
  _m = 0
  def do(self):
     if self._m==0: ...
     elif ...
```

Your original code won't work because Python only looks for `_m` in two places: defined in the function, or as a global. It won't look in class scope like C++ does. So you have to prefix with `self.` so the right one gets used. If you wanted to force it to use the `_m` in `class A`, you would use `A._m` instead.

P.S. There are times you need this pattern, particularly with metaclasses, which are kinda-sorta Python's analog to C++'s template metaprogramming and functional algorithms.

Comment: I forgot to prefix with self: added now. Note it was only presented to illustrate the pattern. You don't need to prefix with the super class in the case of single inheritance.

Comment: The question was about multithreading, not the validity of the code.

Comment: Your question was if an object of class `B` would randomly work like an object of class `C` in multithreaded code. This is inherently vague. I just showed that it's as threadsafe as object member access is. Which is to say there's no reason that `B` or `C` would act like each other because *they can't even see each other's members.*

Comment: It's not vague. B and C both override a static field of A: _m. Running  B().do() gives 1 and C().do() gives 2. What if these 2 statements run in 2 different threads concurrently? Have you an actual experience with this in a MT environment?

Comment: Python multithreading isn't really preemptive if you're running on CPython; there's a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) that ends up acting like a big barrier synchronizer for everything. As for my experience, yes, I have Django running in a multithreaded WSGI environment using an Apache server and its model library makes heavy use of metaclasses. And yet I still can't see what magic thing you think might happen in Python's guts that would cross two values for two members in two different subclasses, and how threading would trigger it.

Comment: I suggest reading the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), starting at 9.3.2 and going through 9.5. Bear in mind that, unlike C++, calling a method on `A` does *not* force the object in question to pretend it's an `A`; it's still a `B` or `C`, and the method could even access things that exist only in `B` or `C` but not in `A`.